# Get the Second Table Set returned by an SP in another SP

Tags: sql-server

I have an SP with following Statements,

```
CREATE  procedure [dbo].[GetData]
 AS
begin  

SELECT 1 AS DataSet1
SELECT 2 AS DataSet2

end
GO
```

Whenever I execute the SP, I get two Dataset which is 1 and 2. I have to call this SP from Another SP and I only need the Second dataset in that SP,

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[SP2]
 AS
begin  

CREATE TABLE #T (Id VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #T
EXEC [dbo].[GetData]  
SELECT * FROM  #T

end
GO
```

But whenever I execute the second SP, I get both the datasets inserted into the table. Is there any way to split the Result sets?

Comment: The short answer is, you can't; not natively in T-SQL anyway. Generally having a procedure that returns a multiple result sets is a design flaw, or is designed specifically to be consumed by an application that can treat the datasets separately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack way to do it with temp tables, but you will need to  change the original stored procedure.

```
/*  START TSQL CODE */

/*  Stored Procedure Definition */

Use Northwind
GO


IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and ROUTINE_NAME = N'uspOrderDetailsByCustomerId'  
    )
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspOrderDetailsByCustomerId]
END


GO

CREATE Procedure dbo.uspOrderDetailsByCustomerId
(
  @CustomerID nchar(5)
, @ResultSetIndicator smallint = 0
)
AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON



    /* ResultSet #1 */

    if (@ResultSetIndicator = 0 OR @ResultSetIndicator = 1)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT 
            c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName /*,c.ContactName,c.ContactTitle,c.[Address],c.City,c.Region,c.PostalCode,c.Country ,c.Phone,c.Fax */
        FROM 
            Customers c 
            JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
        WHERE 
            c.CustomerID = @CustomerID
    END


    /* */
    /* ResultSet #2 */ 

    if (@ResultSetIndicator = 0 OR @ResultSetIndicator = 2)
    BEGIN 

        SELECT o.OrderID,o.CustomerID /* ,o.EmployeeID,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate,o.ShippedDate,o.ShipVia ,o.Freight,o.ShipName,o.ShipAddress,o.OrderID,o.CustomerID,o.EmployeeID,o.OrderDate  */
        FROM 
            Orders o 
         WHERE 
            o.CustomerID = @CustomerID
        ORDER BY 
            o.CustomerID , o.OrderID 

    END


    /* */
    /* ResultSet #3 */

    if (@ResultSetIndicator = 0 OR @ResultSetIndicator = 3)
    BEGIN 
         SELECT od.OrderID,od.ProductID /* ,od.UnitPrice,od.Quantity,od.Discount  */
         FROM 
            [Order Details] od 
         WHERE 
            exists (select null from dbo.Orders  innerOrds where innerOrds.OrderID = od.OrderID and innerOrds.CustomerID = @CustomerID )
         ORDER BY 
            od.OrderID 

    END

    SET NOCOUNT OFF


END

GO 
/* Get everything */


exec dbo.uspOrderDetailsByCustomerId 'ALFKI'




    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCustomer') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TempCustomer
    end


    CREATE TABLE #TempCustomer
    ( 
      [CustomerID] nchar(5)
    , [CompanyName] nvarchar(40)
    )

INSERT INTO #TempCustomer ( [CustomerID] , [CompanyName])
exec dbo.uspOrderDetailsByCustomerId 'ALFKI' , 1

Select * from #TempCustomer



    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempOrders') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TempOrders
    end


    CREATE TABLE #TempOrders
    ( 
        OrderID int
      , [CustomerID] nchar(5)

    )

INSERT INTO #TempOrders ( OrderID , [CustomerID] )
exec dbo.uspOrderDetailsByCustomerId 'ALFKI' , 2

Select * from #TempOrders






    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempOrderDetails') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TempOrderDetails
    end


    CREATE TABLE #TempOrderDetails
    ( 
        OrderID int
      , [ProductID] int

    )

INSERT INTO #TempOrderDetails ( OrderID , [ProductID] )
exec dbo.uspOrderDetailsByCustomerId 'ALFKI' , 3

Select * from #TempOrderDetails


    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempOrderDetails') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TempOrders
    end


    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempOrders') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TempOrders
    end



    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCustomer') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TempCustomer
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I think this will not work in my case because in my scenario the dataset returned is of columns length. i.e the Number of Columns in each dataset is different.